# React - saving a component in the ref callback

Tags: reactjs

So, extract from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

> The ref attribute can be a callback function instead of a name. This callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted. The referenced component will be passed in as a parameter, and the callback function may use the component immediately, or save the reference for future use (or both).

It then only gives an example of using the component immediately. I'm trying to find out how i would use this function to access the component immediately, *and* save the component for future use, as it says we are able to do.

To continue their specific `focus()` and `theInput` example, how would i call `focus()` on the input element, and save it to the `theInput` key in refs?

Or put another way, how would i make the `console.log` in this fiddle return an object with a `theInput` key of the input element's component ref: https://jsfiddle.net/qo3p3fh1/1/

Comment: I have tried returning a value: `<input type="text" ref={ function(component) { React.findDOMNode( component ).focus(); return 'theInput';  }  } />` - no luck

Comment: I have tried assigning it manually to this.refs `var self = this; <input type="text" ref={ function(component) { self.refs.theInput = component; React.findDOMNode( component ).focus(); }  } />` (more out of desperation than anything else - i know the official advice is not to use this.refs inside render functions). still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I included the code here for completeness.

HTML from your fiddle:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Updated react script changing the way refs are used, fiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/mark1z/q9yg70ak/)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs['theInput']).focus();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" ref='theInput'/>
            <input type="button" onClick={ this.submitForm } value="Submit!" />
          </div>
        );
    },
    submitForm: function() {
      console.log( this.refs['theInput'] );
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: perfect - thanks! the docs implied that you could do it from within the callback, but this feels like a proper way to do it!

Comment: It's pretty easy to get it to focus with the ref callback, but to retrieve the value, you'd have to store the ref name to access it later.  I think for this use case, using 'theInput' named ref is cleaner.  The ref callback function is invoked after the component mounts, so both approaches produce the same functionality.

Answer (score 6):

I do not really understand the chosen answer, and the fiddle just returns an empty object.

Further read from [this doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) at the ES6 usage, you will find:

```
render: function() {
  return <TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c} />;
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  this._input.focus();
},
```

So what you need to do is to assign that component to a `var` that you can hang on to, possibly to `this` like in the example, and later you can use `this._input` to control your component.

Comment: yeah - my question's a bit outdated now. if i understood the latest changelog, i think all refs are domnodes now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a good way but it works. Try it ! https://jsfiddle.net/qo3p3fh1/2/

```
<input type="text" ref={ function(component) { React.findDOMNode( component ).focus(); self.refs = {'theInput': component } } } />
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 version

```
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // let textarea get focus when page loaded
    this.textArea.focus();
  }

  sendMessage(e) {
      console.log(this.textArea);
  }

  render() {
    return (    
      <textarea
        placeholder="say something..." ref={(ref) => {
          this.textArea = ref;
        }} onKeyPress={(e) => this.sendMessage(e)} autoComplete="off"
      >
      </textarea>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the below code work for you?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
       this.node.focus()
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" ref={node => this.node = node} />
            <input type="button" onClick={ this.submitForm } value="Submit!" />
          </div>
        );
    },
    submitForm: function() {
      console.log(this.node);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

A good read, [Why not to use](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678#issue-165177220) `findDOMNode()`